# Are these functions equivalent in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm a newbie wit TensorFlow and I've studying it for the last few days.
I want to understand if the following two functions are equivalent or not:

1.

```
softmax = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights), biases, name=scope.name)
```

2.

```
softmax = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
```

If they are in fact different, what is the main difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
softmax1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights), biases, name=scope.name)
```

**is not equal to**

```
softmax2 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
```

since `softmax1` has no softmax calculation at all while `softmax2` does. See the Tensorflow API for [tf.nn.softmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax). The [general idea of a softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) is that it *normalizes* the input by rescaling the whole data sequence ensuring their entries are in the interval (0, 1) and the sum is 1.

The only thing that is equal between the two statements is the basic calculation. `+` does the same thing [tf.add](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#add) does so `tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights), biases)` **is equal** to `tf.matmul(x, weights) + biases`.

---

**EDIT**: To add some clarification (I think you do not know really know what softmax is doing?):

```
tf.matmul(x, W) + bias
```

Calculates a matrix multiplication between `x` (your input vector) and `W` the weights for the current layer. Afterwards the `bias` is added.

This calculation models the *activation* of one layer. Additionally you have an activation function, like the `sigmoid` function which transforms your activation. So for one layer you normally do something like this:

```
h1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W) + bias)
```

Here `h1` would be the activation of this layer.

The `softmax` operation simply rescales your input. E.g., if you got this activation on your output layer:

```
output = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 0.5, 0.2]]
```

The softmax rescales this input for fitting the values in the interval (0, 1) and being the sum equal to 1:

```
tf.nn.softmax(output)
> [[ 0.01497873,  0.0407164 ,  0.11067866,  0.81781083,  0.00908506,
     0.00673038]]

tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax(output))
> 1.0
```

Comment: So,  is it correct say that the 2) is the application of cross-entropy to obtain labels `0.0` or `1.0` for probability, while the 1) need a further passage to obtain 1-hot label ?

Comment: No, this is not correct. `softmax` does not produce a 1-hot encoded vector. The softmax operation rescales your input vector. For getting the cross-entropy as an error you will need to calculate the cross-entropy separately.

Comment: Ok, I understand this.

Comment: I've added an extra explanation with an example for you.

Comment: I'm following the TensorFlow tutorial but many things are obscure.
Maybe for my work I don't need to know all, but I need to create a good model for image recognition to integrate in my own software. But of course I need to understand the passage to create model and convnet in the best way.
I'm not a machine learnig developer, so sorry for elementary questions :)

Comment: Maybe you should stop with the Tensorflow tutorial and rather do something on deeplearning.net or even a YouTube tutorial. If one has no experience with deep neural networks and almost no knowledge about this field the Tensorflow tutorials are quite challenging. In my opinion they are made for people who already developed some nets with other libraries or on their own. If you are a beginner I would suggest starting with an easier tutorial and afterwards returning to Tensorflow.

Comment: Yes, you're right, and I'll do it! Also with your edit I understand what I'm wrong. Thanks!